# ARC NSMutableArray pools

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting

I have a pool of objects I keep inside an NSMutableArray so if any other objects want to reference them instead of creating new objects I will simply give it a reference to an object I have already created.

In the past I would monitor retain/release calls on these objects, and when they reached a retain count of 1 (my array only) I would remove them from the array. However I am struggling to do this with ARC because it doesn't let me monitor retain/release, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: It's a bad practice. Never depend on retainCount.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a way to manage objects based on release/retains calls, it's dangerous. If Apple happens to change the way it works, you are screwed. And apparently, that's what happened, when you start using ARC. There are two things:

1) You want to keep the objects inside the `NSMutableArray` independently if they are being use by other objects or not. In that case, just create a `__weak` reference to that objects, and in that way your object, that is inside the `NSMutableArray`, is kept alive.

2) Once there are not references to the object, just remove it from the `NSMutableArray`. Add to the `NSMutableArray` a `__weak` object. Once the `strong` one is release, the one inside the array will be as well, although I don't really like this approach as I find it dangerous. If you go for this option, use this to store the objects:

```
NSValue *weakObject = [NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:anObject];
[array addObject:weakObject];
```

In the end, you can simply remove ARC from that specific file, and you can keep the monitoring.

Comment: There is a difference between `weak` and `nonretained`.

Comment: non-retained means just that...  `retain` is not called.  That's very different from `weak` where the reference is zeroed when the object is deallocated.

Comment: From Apple Documents: weak
Specifies that there is a weak (non-owning) relationship to the destination object.

If the destination object is deallocated, the property value is automatically set to nil.

(Weak properties are not supported on OS X v10.6 and iOS 4; use assign instead.)

Comment: You can read more here: http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/07/rules-to-avoid-retain-cycles.html

Comment: OK.  Yes, that's what a weak reference is.  But just because something is nonretained does not mean it is weak, which is my whole point.  Your post implies that using non-retained is the same as using weak, which is not even close to being true.

Comment: No because once the retain count is zero, a weak reference would nil it. "Not even close to being true" is a bit strong...

Comment: But your suggestion is **not** a weak reference!  It is merely a non-retained reference.  Two completely different things.

Comment: Yes I concede to you, it's not exactly the same thing. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't bother with such a complex system. Just work with strong and weak properties and don't try to second guess performance. You are trying to build a memory management system yourself which makes little sense with ARC around. Creating and deleting objects is generally a tiny percentage of performance of any objective-c app; after years of using Instruments to monitor performance I don't worry about this part any more.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should write simple code, intended for humans.

Do not worry about such performance issues until you have proven (via instruments or some other measure) that this is a critical bottleneck.

That said, creating certain objects can be really expensive, so keeping a cache for certain objects is not in and of itself a bad idea.  However, you should never rely on reference counts, even in non-ARC code.  Apple docs are very clear about this.

The alternative, as Jacky pointed out is a weak reference.  Unfortunately, you can not put a `weak` reference into standard collections (though, ironically, you can put them in C++ collections and they will be managed correctly).

However, you can create a simple wrapper class to hold a weak reference.

```
@interface WeakWrapper : NSObject
@property (readonly) id object;
- (id)initWithObject:(id)object;
@end

@implementation WeakWrapper {
    __weak id _object;
}
- (id)object {
    return _object;
}
- (id)initWithObject:(id)object {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _object = object;
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

You can then place these objects inside collections, and then...

```
WeakWrapper *wrapper = // get the object from the collection
id object = wrapper.object;
if (nil == object) {
    // You know the object that was being referenced no longer exists
    // so this wrapper can be removed from the collection and destroyed.
}
```